# How do I extract a movie frame with applied filters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-image, qtkit

So I have a `QTMovieView` displaying a `QTMovie`. Via my interface the user can add and remove CoreImage filters that are applied to the movie in real time. That works fine.

Now I want to extract images from the movie (say when the user hits a button). This works too with the `frameImageAtTime` method. **But what I get is an unfiltered image from the original movie.** My guess is that the CI filters are applied tho the `QTMovieView`'s display layer and not to the movie itself.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working solution: Use `frameImageAtTime` to retrieve a `CIImage`, apply the same filters to it as on the `QTMovie` and convert the resulting filtered image into a `NSImage`(via `NSBitmapImageRep`).